# Shell doesn't accept commands after ssh login or R or Python

Tags: shell

This used to work just until recently, no idea what happened maybe an updated version of something is causing the problem.

In the `shell` buffer in Emacs, shell seems to stop working after SSH or launching R or Python. Say, if I launch R in shell buffer, R loads and when I enter any command and press Enter the cursor just moves to a new line, no command is sent. But the shell responds to `C-c C-c` and cancels the command and returns the prompt. I've tried issuing `comint-send-input` manually with `M-x` but that didn't work either. I've also tried this with "bare" Emacs, launching it with the `-Q` option, same.

For SSH, the problem occurs for `bash` but not for `zsh`.

I've just used `zsh` to launch R and I get "^G" inserted at the end of the command after pressing Enter. I think that is the problem. No idea how that occurs, if hadn't tried `zsh` with R never would have seen it as it doesn't print on screen with bash.

GNU Emacs 26.3 on Ubuntu 19.04

Comment: What happens when you do this without emacs, ie. ssh from an xterm?

Comment: No problem in terminal and no problem with `term` in Emacs.

Comment: This sounds weird. What happens if you `ssh localhost`? Whats the user shell (bash, tcsh, zsh, ...) on those servers, would it help to change that to another one?

Comment: `bash` everywhere. With `localhost` I've tried `zsh` and `sh` and both worked fine. So I guess it's `bash` related problem. But on remote server `sh` didn't worked, caused the same problem. Not sure this is the remote server problem, I think my Ubuntu got updated recently and something must have changed in my computer. I will try this from CentOS to CentOS tomorrow.

Comment: I've tried this with Emacs 24.3.1 on the server (CentOS to CentOS), I've connected to another server with `shell`. The same problem. Although these two servers share the same user home directory. I guess this is not an Emacs problem.

Comment: Maybe it is related somehow to the [systemd and tmux/screen problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802189/how-to-run-tmux-screen-with-systemd-230)? (disclaimer: I'm just guessing)

Comment: That didn't work. I wonder why `sh` works with localhost but not the remote server, I could just use `sh`. I only need this to run R on the remote server and use `ess-remote` to make it ESS inferior buffer.

Comment: I've tried this from inside a CentOS 7 VM, installed Emacs and SSH'ed into the localhost, same problem. Is this something to do with the settings of SSH?

Comment: `zhs` seems to work with localhost, can't test it on remote it's not there

Comment: Problem solved it was my .inputrc file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the `.inputrc` file (vi mode) with the following line:

`Control-j: history-search-forward`

As suggested in the jue's comment below, the following solves the problem by restoring the `C-j` to its original binding for `dumb` terminals such as the shell mode in Emacs:

```
$if term=dumb 
    Control-j: accept-line
$else
    Control-j: history-search-forward
$endif
```

I had the same `.inputrc` file everywhere, on the remote servers and the VM.

Big thanks to @jue!

Comment: I think emacs' shell is `dumb` so, working with `$if term=dumb <NEWLINE> $else <YOURSETTINGS> $endif` in your .inputrc could help.

Comment: You are gold! If yo put this as answer I will accept it! Anyway if it wasn't for your suggestion to try `zsh` I would have gone bananas! :)

Comment: Glad I could help and thanks. It is ok for me, when you make your answer the accepted and make it a bit more verbose. Maybe you get some upvotes. :)